# MvvmCross - manually add View to Linear Layout - access model inside event

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I have a page which is a ScrollView. I am going to put some TextViews and some ListViews in it. Because people said: cannot use ListView inside ScrollView, so I use LinearLayout instead.

This is .axml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                local:MvxBind="Text Item.Info1"/>
    <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" />
</ScrollView>
```

This is ViewModel:

```
public class ItemDetailViewModel : MvxViewModel{

    ...

    private Item _item;
    public Item Item {
        get { return this._item; }
        set {
            _item= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Item );
        }
    }

    ....
```

In View, I manually add TextView to linearLayout1. I want to access subItem when click TextView. But I do not know how to do this. Could you please look into below comments and help? Thanks.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    ItemDetailViewModel vm = this.ViewModel as ItemDetailViewModel ;
    RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                LinearLayout linearLayout1 = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);

                foreach (SubItem subItem vm.Item.SubItems)
                {
                    //I am stuck here, don't know how to access subItem in Click event??

                    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                    textView.Text = subItem.itemName;
                    textView.Click += textView_Click;
                    linearLayout1.AddView(textView);

                    //I know there is another way to do this by using existed axml but ...
                    /*
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        local:MvxBind="Text ItemName; Click DoSomethingWithItem" />
                    */
                    TextView textView = (TextView)LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Sub_Item, null);
                    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<.., ItemDetailViewModel >();
                    set.Bind(textView ).To(vm => vm....); //How can I access subItem from vm??
                    set.Apply();

                }
            });
        });
....
private void adEquipmentTextView_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     //TODO:do something with subItem
}
```

Comment: You can not use Scrollable view inside Scroll container view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create an anonymous wrapper for each method?

i.e. instead of calling:

```
                textView.Click += textView_Click;
```

call:

```
                textView.Click += (s,e) => DoClickOn(subItem);
```

Comment: Thank you Stuart, it works. Is there anyway I can achieve this if I use LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Sub_Item, null) and CreateBindingSet?